# No matching bean of type [com.sachin.dao.StockDao] found for dependency

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am getting this error when I am trying to use dependency injection in Spring MVC.

> No matching bean of type [com.sachin.dao.StockDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.sachin.dao.StockDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

I think I am making some mistake in my annotations. I am basically trying to inject StockDaoImpl in my HomController.

This is my controller file HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private final StockDao dao;

@Autowired 
public HomeController(StockDao dao){
    this.dao = dao;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {        
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/stockgoogle/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Stock stockGoogle(Locale locale, Model model) {    
    //StockDaoImpl si = new StockDaoImpl();
    Stock s=dao.listGoogle();
    System.out.println("reached here");
    model.addAttribute("s", s );        
    return s;
}
```

I have created a configuration file BeanConfiguration and using that to create the bean

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {
@Bean
public StockDao stockDao(){
  return new StockDaoImpl();
}
}
```

I have StockDaoImpl to implement my data retreival.

```
public class StockDaoImpl implements StockDao {    
@Override
public Stock listGoogle() {
    Connection con = null;
    Stock s = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        con = DriverManager
           .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/webapp",
           "postgres", "sachin");             
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM \"public\".\"Historical\" " );            

        rs.next();
        String  name = rs.getString("Name");
        s = new Stock(name);                
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();             
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

The above is implementing the following interface:

```
public interface StockDao {
public Stock listGoogle();
}
```

Am I missing something. Is there any more annotations that I have to put. Or at some other place. I am not sure if I am creating the configuration class correctly. Can you please help?

Comment: I'd try adding `@Repository` to the `StockDaoImpl` class, and just `@Autowired` it in the `HomeController` (and remove the constructor entirely).

Comment: Hi @user2478398 thank you for the answer. It is giving may not have been initialized error.

Comment: That's because it's declared `final`.  Removing this modifier should enable you to continue.  If you need it to be `final`, then the `@Autowired` constructor you have is the way to go; just whenever I see an `@Autowired` constructor, I assume there's going to be multiple instances of that class (which wouldn't make much sense for a `@Controller` IMO).

Comment: @user2478398 Ok. I tried that, Still the same error. I think its not able to see the bean definition or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to your configuration class(es). To do that from another Java configuration class (for example, in your BeanConfiguration class), add:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.sachin")
```